# Is otool removed in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, utilities

I can't find `/usr/bin/otool` any more in Mountain Lion.

1. Does anybody know why `otool` is removed?
2. Is there any alternative for `otool` in Mountain Lion.

Comment: I rolled back your changes to the original question. I think it was more clear, and since you marked my answer as correct then I think it should stay this way. If you still have questions about other libraries, you should probably just start a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a somewhat-recent version of the Xcode developer tools, the command-line utilities were moved into a separate package. You can either install them from inside Xcode or just download them separately. See my answer here for more details: [I installed Xcode but I still don't have gcc in my terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45505/i-installed-xcode-but-i-still-dont-have-gcc-in-my-terminal/45506#45506).

Comment: thanks for your answers. But I still find a lot of other libraries can't be found in mountain lion that are depended by existing libraries. How should I resolve this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Have you ever used [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/)?

Comment: I installed Zend CE server on 10.7. It works well. However it doesn't work after I upgraded Mac to mountain lion. I found some system libraries depended by php of Zend CE can't be found in 10.8.

Comment: This sounds like a completely different question, perhaps you should post it separately. It might also help to ask the community of Zend CE.

Comment: thanks for your information. I found a workaround for my php issue.